# Why is Travis CI ignoring my request for a specific Ruby version?

Tags: travis-ci

I had a build like this which was working a year ago:

```
language: java
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.m2
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
install:
  - gem install buildr
script: buildr clean upload
```

But unfortunately, one of the libraries buildr wants now requires Ruby 2.0:

```
ERROR:  Error installing buildr:
    net-ssh requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
```

(Source: https://travis-ci.org/trejkaz/hex-components/builds/224629263)

So I tried updating the build as follows:

```
language: java
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.m2
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
rvm:
  - 2.0
install:
  - gem install buildr
script: buildr clean upload
```

The error is the same:

```
ERROR:  Error installing buildr:
    net-ssh requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
```

I followed the docs as best I could and it seems like it doesn't use the version of Ruby I'm specifically asking for.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `rvm` only works with `language: ruby`. Since the base image for TravisCI is Ubuntu 12.04 (14.04 soon), that is going to have Ruby < 2.0 installed on the system (14.04 too actually; it has 1.9.3).

Comment: That... is definitely it. Apparently switching to `language: ruby` did work, as `jdk` does exist for `ruby`. Go figure. It's a Java project, so I would have expected to declaratively say to use Java here, but maybe all this really means is that `language` is a bad abstraction for classifying OS images for a build server. I mean, my project might be like the one I work on at work, which has ObjC, C++, Java and Ruby all in the one big mess.

Comment: Would you like me to get the comment composed into an answer?

Comment: Yeah, might as well do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial reason why `buildr` was unable to be installed is because the current image for Travis CI is Ubuntu 12.04, which has Ruby 1.8 for the system Ruby. Soon this will be updated to Ubuntu 14.04, which has Ruby 1.9 for the system's Ruby install. Unfortunately, both of these are below the required 2.0 which you need to install the gem for your project.

The method you tried with `rvm` was the right idea, but does not work for `language: java`. However, it does work for `language: ruby`. Conveniently, the `jdk` key does work with `language: ruby` due to the support for `JRuby`. Note the documentation below:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/

A slight modification to your `.travis.yml` moves you forward:

```
language: ruby
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.m2
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
rvm:
  - 2.0
install:
  - gem install buildr
script: buildr clean upload
```

As you noted in your comment, Travis CI makes a bold and dangerous assumption about a project not being multi-language when it defines the base environment with `language`, which can cause problems like the one you have observed in your question.